Wget not resolving correctly on hosted domain
I have an Ubuntu 22.04 server with Plesk Obsidian  on it with multiple VHosts. Now, I need to call an API from my own domain (hosted on this server): https://www.example.com/api. When I do this locally on my PC, for example, using wget or curl:
wget https://www.example.com/api

It works, and I get the expected result. However, when I execute the same command on my Plesk server over ssh, I get a 404 error.
As a test, I also tried:
wget https://www.example.com/

And as expected, on my PC, I get the HTML file of my homepage. But when I run the same command on the server, I get the Plesk default page, which normally shows up on newly created domains.
It looks like, that the vhosts aren't working correctly, when trying to reach them from the same machine. But I had never problems with this server and setup so far.
Any ideas?

Turns out, that the problem was the IPv6 resolving. Forcing wget to use IPv4 works:
wget --inet4-only https://www.example.com/api

